# Installing apr on Windows through MinGW, Python not detected

Tags: python, mingw32, log4cxx, apr

I'm trying to install log4cxx with MinGW on my Windows box but need to install apr and apr-util first.

I've been following **[the guide on Apache's website](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4cxx/MSWindowsBuildInstructions)** and installed the version of Python they listed but get an error about Python not being found:

```
$ buildconf
buildconf: checking installation...
buildconf: python not found.
           You need python installed
           to build APR from SVN.
```

I used the **[Python installer](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.5/python-2.5.msi)** linked in the guide so I assume it's the correct version.

Do I have to tell MinGW or MSYS where Python is and, if so, how do I actually do that?

Also, everything is running 32-bit right now.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the location where you installed Python to your PATH environment variable.  I would go to the following [link](http://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html#setting-envvars) that discusses setting PATH in Windows

Comment: I just tried adding C:\Python25 in my PATH variable but it didn't seem to do the trick. I'll try seeing if MinGW Shell has it's own path that it sets.

Comment: Another sanity check you might try is to see if you can run python from command prompt.  That would be a good way of ensuring your PATH variable is set correctly.  My guess is MinGW somehow uses the System PATH (or a modified version of it).  Cygwin looks at the System PATH as well.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add the path  in MinGw C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\etc in the fstab file as below

Win32_Path      Mount_Point
c:/mingw        /mingw

c:/ActiveState/perl /perl

C:/Python25